# Serializing enum with name() and value

Tags: java, groovy, enums, jackson

I have a simple (groovy) enum:

```
enum OutputType { 
  skip( 'gray' ), left( 'orange' ), right( 'cyan' )

  final String color
  
  private OutputType( String color ) {
    this.color = color
  }  
}
```

I want to serialize it with Jackson so it looks like (pseudo-JSON):

```
{ skip:gray, left:orange, right:cyan }
```

or in other words a `name()` to `color` Object.

How to achieve that with plain Jackson?

Comment: You'll have to write your own `JsonSerializer` to do this.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis for now I do `OutputType.values().collectEntries{ [ it.name(), it.color ] }`

Comment: @injecteer, converting it to a `Map` and serializing it as a raw object is probably the simplest (best) option. `JsonSerializer` is used to serialize instance not a whole `enum` as a `JSON Obect`.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your enum looks like this:

```
public enum OutputType {

    SKIP("gray"),
    LEFT("orange"),
    RIGHT("cyan");

    private final String color;
    public String getColor() { return color; }

    OutputType(String color) {
    this.color = color;
    }

}
```

You will need to extend Jackson's `JsonSerializer` like so and create your own implementation:

```
public class OutputTypeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<OutputType> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(OutputType value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
    if (null == value) {
        gen.writeNull();
    } else {
        gen.writeString(value.getColor());
    }
    }

}
```

Then assuming you have a `dto` with an `OutputType` field the only thing needed for this to work is adding the correct annotation like so:

```
public class OutputDto {
       
    @JsonSerialize(using = OutputTypeSerializer.class)
    private OutputType type;
    public OutputType getType() { return type; }
    public void setType(OutputType type) { this.type = type; }
    
}
```

Conversely, you can implement a `JsonDeserializer` should you need to re-create an `OutputType` object from a given `JSON` resource.

Comment: This will generate something like `{"type":"gray"}`.